# Batch command to move all files of certain extension

Tags: windows, batch

I have a script which uses 7zip to extract all rar files which is great.

The only problem is then I have to manually go through the folders and move the .avi or .mkv files.

The script I am currently using

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%
    cd %%F
        FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
            "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X
        )
    popd
)
```

My current setup:

D:\rared\loads of folders names, then I move them all to D:\rared\extracted

Is there a way to modify the first script or just write another one to move all the files in all sub directories to the extracted folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the  7z command line you have, adding -oD:\rared\extracted

So `"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X`
becomes
 `"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x %%X -oD:\rared\extracted`

Comment: note- looks like you can change 7z e for 7z x, or keep 7z x. whichever.  Also I haven't tried your setup. so it's not entirely tested in an ideal sense, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late.  Below is what I would do.  I set the min file size of 12,345KB to avoid all those annoying Sample clips (adj up  as you wish). I have absolutely no way of testing it because I use rar.exe, the e/x shouldn't matter.  Let me know if this works for you or if you want some other feature or if you have any ?s

```
SetLocal
Set BaseDir     =D:\Rars\
Set TempDir     =D:\rared\extracted\
Set GoodStuff   =D:\GoodStuffToWatch\
Set MinFileSize =12345

FOR /R %BaseDir% %%F in (*.RAR *.ZIP) DO "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~fF" -o%TempDir%
FOR /R %TempDir% %%G in (*.AVI *.MKV) DO IF %%~zG GTR %MinFileSize% Move "%%~fG" %GoodSTufF%
```